# Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression ANGULAR 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

**The error showing in time of npm run build**

```
    Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression [getImageUrl(image, true);] in E:/Work/JamesJ/Pixie/pixie-image-editor/source/src/app/image-editor-ui/panels/open-sample-image-panel/open-sample-image-panel.component.html@34:9 ("

<div class="samples" *ngIf="sampleImages" >
    <img [ERROR ->][src]="getImageUrl(image, true);" *ngFor="let image of sampleImages" (click)="openSampleImage(image)"")
: Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression [getImageUrl(image, true);] in E:/Work/JamesJ/Pixie/pixie-image-editor/source/src/app/image-editor-ui/panels/open-sample-image-panel/open-sample-image-panel.component.html@34:9 ("

<div class="samples" *ngIf="sampleImages" >
    <img [src]="getImageUrl(image, true);" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let image of sampleImages" (click)="openSampleImage(image)">
</div>")
: Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at the end of the expression [getImageUrl(image, true);] in E:/Work/JamesJ/Pixie/pixie-image-editor/source/src/app/image-editor-ui/panels/open-sample-image-panel/open-sample-image-panel.component.html@34:9 ("ngIf="sampleImages" >
    <img [src]="getImageUrl(image, true);" *ngFor="let image of sampleImages" [ERROR ->](click)="openSampleImage(image)">
</div>")
```

**html code is**

```
    <div class="samples" *ngIf="sampleImages" >
    <img [src]="getImageUrl(image, true);" *ngFor="let image of sampleImages" (click)="openSampleImage(image)">
</div>
```

**and component code is :**

```
public getImageUrl(image: SampleImage, useThumbnail = false) : string {
    const url = (image.thumbnail && useThumbnail) ? image.thumbnail : image.url;
    // prefix relative link with base url, if needed
    if (url.indexOf('//') === -1) {
        return this.config.getAssetUrl(url);
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[src]="getImageUrl(image, true)"` remove the semi colon

Comment: have you tried to remove semicolon here? [src]="getImageUrl(image, true);"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove the semicolon:

```
    <img [src]="getImageUrl(image, true)" ...>
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be a comment rather than an answer, how it's gonna be useful for the community?

Comment: @Vikas - People who look for "Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression" will find this answer and get the solution.

Comment: Why so @Vikas? It's an answer to his question. It's useful to anybody who made the same mistake as him.

Comment: @DánielBarta Can you add some explanation why it is a mistake to add semicolon after it? I did not know actually, thats why asking. And yes, its working.

Comment: @AbdurRahim I'm glad. The reason is exactly what you got in the error message: you can only bind one expression to a property.  The reason mainly is that this is how angular works. With the semicolon, you close your expression, so it doesn't parse the return value of your expression. On the other hand, for events, you can do this: `<div (click)="someCallback(); console.log('hi')"...`

Comment: @DánielBarta Thanks I understood the reason behind it. :)